# Excel Index with count function no working?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I'm trying to use an index with count function to return the last number in a specific array.

I have numeric data in C6:C17 and I want that F6 returns the last value from that array (C6:C7).

I've used this formula: `=INDEX(C6:C17;COUNT(C6:C17))` and it works perfectly.

But when I use this formula: `=INDEX(C6:C17;COUNT(C6:C17)-4)`, it returns the value of the fourth previous row. If I only have values on C6, C7, C8, C9 and the rest is empty, it returns the value of C6. If I choose F7 instead of F6 to return the value, the same formula gives me the value of C7.

It shouldn't give me an error, since my -4 is now outside of the array. It only happens in the row before the row where the array starts.

If I put (-5) in the same formula and with the same values, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `0` is a viable option for the row return:

```
=INDEX(C6:C17;0)
```

Will return the entire range as an array and since that array is being put in the one cell and not many through an array formula it returns the first value only of the array, `C6`.

Negatives are not a viable option:

```
=INDEX(C6:C17;-1)
```

will error.

If you want to stop that from happening you need to test if 0.  A quick way is to get the reciprocal  of the reciprocal:

```
=INDEX(C6:C17;1/(1/(COUNT(C6:C17)-4)))
```

This will now throw an error instead of returning the value if the count is less than 5.

Or you can just test and return a negative:

```
=INDEX(C6:C17;IF(COUNT(C6:C17)>4;COUNT(C6:C17)-4;-1))
```